# How to create a ctypes.BigEndianStructure that contains ctypes.Union?

Tags: c, python-3.x, ctypes

I am trying to port some C code to Python 3.6 using the `ctypes` library, but I was not able to create a `ctypes.BigEndianStructure` that contains a `ctypes.Union`. It raises `TypeError: This type does not support other endian`.

The exception seems adequate, since looking at the [ctypes documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ctypes.html#structured-data-types) for class `Union`, it clearly says that it is a base class for unions in **native** byte order, and my native byte order is little endian (not what is needed in this case).

Let me illustrate my code.

`code.c`:

```
typedef struct header {
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int b;
} header;

typedef struct body {
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int b;
} body;

typedef struct structure {
    union {
        struct header header;
        char _fill[0x10];
    } header;
    union {
        struct body body;
        char _fill[0x10];
    } body;
} structure;
```

`code.py`:

```
import ctypes

class header(ctypes.BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('a', ctypes.c_uint),
        ('b', ctypes.c_uint)
    ]

class body(ctypes.BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('a', ctypes.c_uint),
        ('b', ctypes.c_uint)
    ]

class _header(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [ 
        ('header', header),
        ('_fill', ctypes.c_char*0x10),
    ]

class _body(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [ 
        ('body', body),
        ('_fill', ctypes.c_char*0x10),
    ]

#class structure(ctypes.Structure): # <-- works, but it is not what I need.
class structure(ctypes.BigEndianStructure): # <-- raises TypeError.
    _fields_ = [
        ('header', _header),
        ('body', _body),
    ]
```

How should I proceed with the creation of the structure?

Comment: Documentation mentions `BigEndianUnion`, but it doesn't actually exist.

Comment: What you have seems to work, though.  The two inner BigEndian structures *are* big-endian, and since there are no new fields other then nested unions in the outer structure, the byte layout is actually correct and it doesn't matter if the outer structure is big- or little-endian.  If I set a/b in header and body, they are big-endian in the final structure, and padded out to 0x10 bytes according to the union.

Comment: If that isn't what you want, just use native structure, but byte-swap the values in the fields  yourself, similar to the C socket function `htonl`.